# cookiecutter step when installing Pyramid application throws module not found error

Tags: python, pyramid, cookiecutter

I was trying to create Pyramid application using cookiecutter. After installing cookiecutter in my Debian GNU/linux 10 system and adding the path of ~/local to bash profile, the cookiecutter application is available for use. But when I run

```
cookiecutter gh:Pylons/pyramid-cookiecutter-starter --checkout 2.0-branch
```

I get the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/cdit/.local/bin/cookiecutter", line 6, in <module>
    from cookiecutter.__main__ import main
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'cookiecutter'
```

Please help to fix this error

Comment: should i install gh client ?

Answer (score 1):

I **activated the virtual environment** and then installed cookiecutter ***within the virtual environment*** using :

```
pip install cookiecutter
```

Then run the cookiecutter command. It worked!